# How to learn if a remote linux machine has booted?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux

I have a Windows development machine, and a Linux target on a company network. After booting the target board, how do i learn if it has booted up ? `ping` `dig` `host` `nslookup` utilities with target name do not resolve the IP address and hence do not reply. The board has Busy box utilities only.

I have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/281542/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-unix-linux-machine-whose-name-i-know) post, but the problem still stands.

Comment: Does this need the embedded-linux tag? Anyway, if it's not responding, then it's not online. Is there someone in the company responsible for this machine that you can contact/

Comment: @Joe Frambach : It probably needs the embedded linux tag since the target is an embedded linux device, with bare minimum utilities

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear. Well, someone else already edited the tag out.

Comment: Any sane reason for down voting ?

Comment: It's downvoted (and soon closed) since it's off-topic. You should have posted it on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you develop for a Linux system, do yourself a favor: install Linux on your desktop or laptop. You'll learn much faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. do you know the IP address or the hostname for this target board ?

if yes,

1. does it respond to `ssh host_name_or_ip_here` command ?

if yes and if busybox utilities are installed, you can execute

```
ssh remote_target "/bin/busybox uptime"
```

and parse the output on your windows machine to see if the board is up for a short time, which means it rebooted recently.

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I am on a network using DHCP service, so do not know the IP address of the machine. The issue is to discover the device on windows machine as soon as it boots

Comment: since this machine is expecting to accept some incoming connections, there should be some way of knowing its address or DHCP name. Without knowing your organization's network architecture, it is very difficult to make a guess. How do you know what IP address or hostname to connect to, prior to this reboot then ?

Comment: Currently I can check the ip address after reading from terminal over serial port ?!

Comment: does this box respond to ssh/rsh/rexec or any other interactive connection request ?

Comment: This box will work normally if IP address is used, but since the device does not have static IP, revery reboot might change the IP. So the idea is to discover the device on network independent of its IP address.
The `ping <hostname>` does not respond.

Comment: then you have to do something on the system to advertise its new IP address after every reboot. Something like ssh'ing (under busy box tools there is an ssh client I believe) to a master server and echo'ing its own IP to a file, to which you have access to. Such as running something like this : `IP=$(ifconfig -a|grep "inet addr:"|grep -v "127.0.0"); ssh masterservername "echo ${IP} /tmp/MyNewIP.out"` at the end of the boot sequence, or periodically via cron

Comment: I think you have almost answered the query, one more thing if you can suggest is there a way to write this to a windows machine, since busybox will not have samba client ?

Comment: Well, I am not a windows expert but one thing I know, it doesn't have a Unix like shell for my command to be valid. And I am by no means a Windows machine expert. But common sense suggests you run an ftp server on this windows machine (free ones are many, just google it) then create an account on this ftp server on the windows machine. After reboot, create a file on busybox with IP address as content of this file and run `busybox ftpput -u username -p password win_machine_IP_address Here_is_my_new_IP.txt local_file_on_busybox_containing_IP`

Comment: Thank you. that sounds like a solution.